# Is There a way to check if keydown inputs are pressed in a specified sequence?

Tags: javascript, input, keydown

I'm Trying to implement a cheat-code like function in my website where if a person enters a sequence(like right up left down(using arrow keys)), an element of the website changes.

Currently, I've made simple things where through using an event listener, i checked the event keys to ArrowLeft,ArrowRight and so on,and added counters respectively.The only problem here is that it isn't checking the sequence of the inputs, so if the keys are pressed in any order, the element will change.
The current code I have is:

```
var i = document.getElementById("ind");
        var Ltrigger = 0, Rtrigger = 0, Utrigger = 0, Dtrigger = 0;
        document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
            switch (event.key) {
                case "ArrowLeft":
                    Ltrigger++;
                    break;
                case "ArrowRight":
                    Rtrigger++;
                    break;
                case "ArrowUp":
                    Utrigger++;
                    break;
                case "ArrowDown":
                    Dtrigger++;
                    break;
            }
            if (Ltrigger == 1 && Rtrigger == 1 && Utrigger == 1 && Dtrigger == 1) {
                i.style.backgroundColor = 'aqua'
                i.innerHTML = "<h3>SUCCESS</h3>"
            }
        })
```

Comment: push them to an array and check the order in the array.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/hotkeys-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Keep a cumulative array or string of the keys so far, in order

```js
const i = document.getElementById("ind");
const sequenceElement = document.getElementById("sequence");

var keys = "";

document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
  keys += " " + event.key
  sequenceElement.innerHTML="You have pressed:\n"+keys;
  
  if (keys.endsWith(" ArrowUp ArrowDown ArrowLeft ArrowRight")) {
    i.style.backgroundColor = 'aqua'
    i.innerHTML = "<h3>SUCCESS</h3>"
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="ind">
  Press arrows in this sequence: up, down, left, right.
</div>

<br>

<div id="sequence">
Sequence of keypresses will appear here. This is just for your understanding - remove it in your final program.
</div>
```